# How can I do to serialize a queryset with foreign fields?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, serialization

I have a problem, I have two tables

```
class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=None)
    begin = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True)
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default=None)
```

Then, I tried to serialize using this :

```
car_query = Car.objects.filter(year=1984)
car_json = serializers.serialize('json', car)
car = json.loads(car_json)
```

It works but I have just the id of the entry in the table Brand. What I would like to have is the name of the Brand inside the variable car.

I thought to try this :

```
car_query = Car.objects.filter(year=1984).values('year', 'begin', 'brand__name')
```

In this case I have a valuesqueryset and then when I try this :

```
car_json = serializers.serialize('json', car_query)
car = json.loads(car_json)
```

I got this : `{AttributeError}'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'` because car_query is not a queryset but valuesqueryset that is the problem.

So I try this `car_json = json.dumps(car_query)` but I have some datetime and it does not work so I decide to try this :

```
json.dumps(car_query, sort_keys=True, indent=1, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

but it does not work. It is strange because when I use `serializers.serialize` the datetime are in the good format but when I use `json.loads` I have some `datetime`.

I precise my goal is just to have at the end a variable `car` which contains all the fields of the table `Car` and the field `name` of the table `Brand`.

Comment: That's due to the `.values(..)`.

Comment: Yes I know but it is the only solution that I found to get the field name of the table Brand.

Answer (score 0):

you can create models method to get brand name

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default=None)

class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=None)
    begin = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True)

    def get_brand(self):
        return self.brand.name
```

and in serializers.py, add models method into fields

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = [field.name for field in Car._meta.fields]
        fields += ['get_brand']
```